# interact with website using android webview

Tags: javascript, android, plugins, webview

I run a forum which has a shoutbox plugin installed where users can talk to each other just like instant messaging. I decided to make what i thought would be a quick app which would just display the shoutbox so users could talk while on the go instead of using there browser. The problem i have found is that it all works great using android webview but when you try and send a shout it comes up with an error saying "fail!" as though it has no communication with the actual shoutbox.

My question is can webview be used like this or can it only be used to display a webpage with out actually interacting with it? Below is my code what i am using so you guys can see if i am missing anything and if so please point me in the right direction thanks.

```
public class splash extends Activity {

        WebView mWebView;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            final Activity mActivity = this;
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Adds Progrss bar Support
            this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
            setContentView(R.layout.mainx);


            // Makes Progress bar Visible
            getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);

            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.webview);
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);     
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.myforum.com/forums/shoutbox.php");


            mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() 
            {
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)  
                {
                    //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes string to Loading...
                    mActivity .setTitle("Loading...");
                    mActivity .setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded

                    // Return the app name after finish loading
                    if(progress == 100)
                    {
                       setTitle(R.string.title);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating and setting a

`WebViewClient`

subclass. It will be called when things happen that impact the rendering of the content, eg, errors or form submissions. You can also intercept URL loading here (via `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`).